How can I store a JSON file in a SQL Server database using ballerina?
I have a SQL Server database table with this structure:
CREATE TABLE json_file_table 
(
    file_id VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    json_value VARBINARY(MAX)
);

How to write a SQL query to insert value into the database and bind values to that query in Ballerina?

json_value VARBINARY(MAX) is an odd decision, it's probably best to use NVARCHAR(MAX)

@Charlieface Thanks for the suggestion. Will take look at that as well.

First you need to convert your json value into a byte[]
json a = { "name": "John", "age": 30 };
byte[] b = a.toString().toBytes();

Then you needs to create a sql:varBinaryValue instance using above bytes.
sql:VarBinaryValue varBinaryValue = new sql:VarBinaryValue(b).
Then use that varBinaryValue in your sql query.
import ballerina/sql;
public function main() {
    json a = { "name": "John", "age": 30 };
    byte[] b = a.toString().toBytes();
    sql:VarBinaryValue varBinaryValue = new sql:VarBinaryValue(b);

    // use this varBinaryValue in a SQL query
}


Assuming you are using NVARCHAR as the column type for json_value, you can use the toJsonString method to convert JSON to a string and store it as a string.
public isolated function insertJSON(jdbc:Client dBCon, string fileId, json jsonValue) returns error? {

sql:ParameterizedQuery insertQuery = `INSERT INTO json_file_table
                ([file_id], [json_value])
            VALUES
                (${fileId},${jsonValue.toJsonString()});`;
any|error? result = dBCon->execute(insertQuery);

}
